# Error in getting active access token from FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having the following code to access FB graph API.

```
var fb1 = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb1.Get( "oauth/access_token", new
{
  client_id = "523408...",
  client_secret = "25bd19645....",
  grant_type = "client_credentials");
}

var apptoken = result.access_token;

        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(apptoken);
        dynamic FriendList = fb.Get("me");
        string t = FriendList.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

But when I execute it, it is giving this error "(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Can somebody please tell me how to get active access token using C# code?

Answer (score 1):

The "User" generates the Access Token, not the server.

This page gives you a way to do it thru Facebook CSharp SDK:

I personally use Facebook JavaScript SDK for the Login and pass the Access Token to the server to make calls.

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/permissions/

This page gives you information about different authentication workflows:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think access token and user (me) they're not the same person. Check Access token and user. I think we all have this problem.